# Serialized form for javascript

Tags: javascript, serialization, symfony-forms, symfony

I need to manage a complex form entirely with Javascript.

I would not like to serve the entire form HTML markup to the user.

That's why I'd need to serialize the form so I can manipulate it with JS while the user fiddles with some HTML interactivity before submitting back to the server.

I saw [this pretty old question](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/symfony2/Nz3fd-07OsA) and this ["deprecated" bundle](https://github.com/simplethings/SimpleThingsFormSerializerBundle)

The question is simple: **How can I serialize a Symfony form's underlying data** ?

---

Here was my first attempt, after having implemented `JsonSerializable` on the related objects:

```
{% form.vars.data|json_encode %}
```

But obviously this encodes the entire objects exposed properties

Comment: You tried to do that: Use jquery ajax call with json and serializer component from Symfony (http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)

Comment: Is there any explanation why this question would deserve to be closed ?

Comment: Now that I see the global reason of close, I think I understand why: Maybe one can't know what I was trying to serialize in the form. Now I tell it in the updated question: The underlying data configured for the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we can easily deserialize a submitted form with the standard Symfony tools, I thought there would be tools to serialize it in the same format. Well that doesn't seem to be the case.

We seem to have to implement our own serializer, here is how it could look like:

```
static public function serializeForm(FormInterface $form)
{
    if (!$form->all()) {
        return $form->getViewData();
    }
    $data = array();
    foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
        $data[$child->getName()] = self::serializeForm($child);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

I took the interesting part from the so called "deprecated" [SimpleThingsSerializerBundle](https://github.com/simplethings/SimpleThingsFormSerializerBundle)'s [form serializer](https://github.com/simplethings/SimpleThingsFormSerializerBundle/blob/master/Serializer/FormSerializer.php#L134)